# Ef table splitting

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Could somebody explain why

```
class TestA
{
    public int TestAId { get; set; }
    public string A { get; set; }
    public TestB TestB { get; set; }
}

class TestB
{
    public int TestBId { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public TestA TestA { get; set; }
}

class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TestA> TestAs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TestB>().Property(t => t.TestBId).HasColumnName("TestAId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<TestB>().HasRequired(t => t.TestA).WithRequiredDependent(t => t.TestB);
        modelBuilder.Entity<TestB>().ToTable("Test");
        modelBuilder.Entity<TestA>().ToTable("Test");
    }
}
```

works great, but if I try to make `TestB` principal

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<TestB>().Property(t => t.TestBId).HasColumnName("TestAId");
    modelBuilder.Entity<TestB>().HasRequired(t => t.TestA).WithRequiredPrincipal(t => t.TestB);
    modelBuilder.Entity<TestB>().ToTable("Test");
    modelBuilder.Entity<TestA>().ToTable("Test");
}
```

it fails with the exception:

> Multiple identity columns specified for table 'Test'. Only one
>   identity column per table is allowed. It's look like a bug.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.itorian.com/2013/10/multiple-identity-columns-specified-for.html)

Comment: The first code sample throws the exception. Not the second.